# Javascript every() display different value when doing a return and console.log()

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a simple algorithm where you evaluate that every number in an array is greater than the next one, so I first taught in the Every() method, but when I do a return is always false, but when I console.log() it display true!

How is this possible?

```
const arr = [3, 2, 1];

const returnRes = arr.every((value, index, arr) => value > arr[index + 1]);

const consoleLogRes = arr.every((value, index, arr) => console.log(value > arr[index + 1]));

console.log(returnRes);
```

[Evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoZ8w.png)

Comment: The every method only returns true if the test returns true for all items in the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: You have your return values mixed up. the `true` you see is the inner `console.log()` printing `true` once, and then the `every` terminates because `console.log()` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

At the third iteration. The value  arr[index + 1] will be undefine. why? it because the value of  arr[index + 1] will be arr(2+1) which is arr[3] and arr[3] does not exist because index start from zero not 1. what you can do is to add a check at the last iteration to prevent the undefine from happening. check the code below

```
const arr = [3, 2, 1];

const response = arr.every((value, index, arr) => {
   
  if (index + 1 === arr.length) {
    return true;
  }
  return value > arr[index + 1];
});

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when your `value` is `1` and `index` is `2`, that is, when the `every` function processes the last element of your array, `arr[index + 1]` returns `undefined` and `1 > undefined` evaluates to `false`.

To properly fix it, you should return `true` when `index` is pointing to the last element:

```js
const arr = [3, 2, 1];

const returnRes = arr.every((value, index, arr) =>
  index === arr.length - 1 || value > arr[index + 1]);

console.log(returnRes);
```